# Array of Records and File Processing

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I am trying to figure out why my file will not output. It is a data file including monitors and their refresh rates, response times, model of the monitor and brand. Whenever I run it I get at.util.Scanner errors and at com.company.MonitorsTest.loadMonitors error. Is the way the data file set up okay?

```
    class Monitors{
     public String brandName;
     public int modelNumber;
    public int refreshRate;
    public int responseTime;
}
public class MonitorsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)   {
        Monitors[] gaming = new Monitors[100];
        int dataFile;
        int choice;

        System.out.println("\nDisplay  Monitors\n");


        System.out.println(" Enter one of the following commands:");
        System.out.println("(1)- Display the entire data file ");
        System.out.println("(2) - Display certain information on a monitor");
        System.out.println("(3) - Display a histogram");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter 1,  2,  or 3  ");
          choice = keyboard.nextInt();

          dataFile = (loadMonitors(gaming));


              while ( choice != 3){
             if (choice < 1 || choice > 3) {
                 System.out.println("Enter 1,  2,  3  ");
                 choice = keyboard.nextInt();
             }
             else if (choice == 1){
                 System.out.println(dataFile);
             }
              }
    }


    private static int loadMonitors(Monitors[] gaming)  {
        int nMonitors = 0;
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\kento\\IdeaProjects\\Program3\\src\\monitors.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            do {
                gaming[nMonitors] = new Monitors();
                gaming[nMonitors].brandName = scan.next();// Error here
                gaming[nMonitors].modelNumber = scan.next();// Error here
                gaming[nMonitors].responseTime = scan.nextDouble();
                gaming[nMonitors].refreshRate = scan.nextInt();// Error here
                ++nMonitors;
            }

            while (gaming[nMonitors - 1].refreshRate != 0);
            --nMonitors;
        }
        catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(" File access error" + ioe);
            nMonitors = 0;
        }
        return nMonitors;


        }
```

List of Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at com.company.MonitorsTest.loadMonitors(MonitorsTest.java:62)
at com.company.MonitorsTest.main(MonitorsTest.java:39)
```

Text file

```
Sceptre DCIP3       1       165
AOC     C24G1A      1       165
ASUS    VG278QR     05      144
Sceptre E22          5      75
Alienware   AW2521HF 1      240
```

Comment: Can you post the full text of the errors you get please?  And also add a comment in the source code to tell us what lines the errors originate from.

Comment: Which lines are 62 and 39?

Comment: 39 is the dataFile = (loadMonitors(gaming));   62 is Size=scan.nextInt();

Comment: Well apparently "size" is not an integer in your data file.  Can you tell us which index this error occurs on (i.e., the value of `nMonitors`, how many monitors have you read so far) and also show us that entry in the data file so we can take a look.

Comment: Beware that `nextInt` is leaving a dangling new line character in the buffer, which subsequent `nextInt` calls won't appreciate

Comment: What does the text file structure look like?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I think the problem is `nextInt` followed by `nextLine`.  `nextInt` should skip over any white space, including newlines.

Comment: @markspace I was looking at the keyboard input ;)

Comment: Oh right.  Yeah that can go wrong in a hurry.  OP: I think the keyboard input is OK now but be careful if you extend this program to read more user options, it can be fussy to use Scanner for this.

Comment: @markspace yeah i tried size but the data file is model number. sorry i forgot to change it but even before i couldnt get it to run but I do think it is something with the nextInt

Comment: We need to be precise here, so "the code is kinda close" doesn't really cut it.  Please edit your code and add the actual reads you are using.  There's one value that is mostly integers but one is a decimal (0,5).  That looks like the mostly likely culprit.

Comment: @SimplyKenton Look at you data, `Sceptre DCIP3       1       165`, your reading `String`, `int`, `double`, `int`, but there are two strings at the start.  In fact it looks more like it should read `String`, `String`, `int`, `int`

Comment: @MadProgrammer ahh you are right. I ended up switching that out and  now I get a java.util.Scanner.throwfor error. Does that mean my scanner can't read the file?

Comment: @SimplyKenton Your `Monitors` class is now incorrect, it won't compile.  I was able to build a parser which worked

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am sorry I am a beginner and I am not too sure what a parser is. but I have to make changes to my Monitors class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question code keeps changing, so it's not 100% possible to point a finger on the exact issue, but, I suspect that the data doesn't match the parsing workflow.

For me, I'd read the next line of data and then parse it separately, for example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        System.out.println(loadMonitors(new Monitors[100]));
    }

    class Monitors {
        public String brandName;
        public String modelNumber;
        public int refreshRate;
        public double responseTime;
    }

    private int loadMonitors(Monitors[] gaming) {
        int nMonitors = 0;
        try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/stackoverflow/monitors.txt"); Scanner scan = new Scanner(is)) {
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                Scanner parser = new Scanner(line);

                System.out.println(line);

                Monitors monitor = new Monitors();
                monitor.brandName = parser.next();
                monitor.modelNumber = parser.next();
                monitor.responseTime = parser.nextDouble();
                monitor.refreshRate = parser.nextInt();

                gaming[nMonitors] = monitor;
                ++nMonitors;
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(" File access error" + ioe);
            nMonitors = 0;
        }
        return nMonitors;

    }
}
```

This will then output

```
Sceptre DCIP3       1       165
AOC     C24G1A      1       165
ASUS    VG278QR     0.5     144
Sceptre E22          5      75
Alienware   AW2521HF 1      240
5
```

*nb: Please note, I'm treating the `monitors.txt` file as an embedded resources, since your original code has it stored in the `src` directory, the above example is a more correct way for reading it.

Comment: ahhh i see what you did. this helped a ton thank you so much!